# Why is the sizeof expression not a compile-time constant like 2, 4, 8, etc.?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, sizeof, compile-time-constant

My compiler is the latest VC++ 2013 preview.

```
int main()
{
    __declspec(align(4))           int n1 = 0; // OK.
    __declspec(align(sizeof(int))) int n2 = 0; // error C2059: syntax error : 'sizeof'
}
```

**Why is the sizeof expression not a compile-time constant like 2, 4, 8, etc.?**

Comment: It says "syntax error" so maybe the parser is expecting a numeric constant. On my unix machine "int a[sizeof(int)];" at the global level compiles ok.

Comment: The `__declspec` stuff is an MSVC specific extension syntax for which they have a set of [nebulous rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx), and clearly, it is not subject to standard rules. In that sense, I don't think it matters whether `sizeof()` is a compile-time constant or not, because I think those extensions are processed outside of the rest of the compilation (i.e., something in between a MACRO and a proper C++ construct). In short, MSVC makes its own rules here, and you just have to live with them, if it doesn't like `sizeof()`, then you can't use it there.

Comment: It appears that MS defines the [`__alignof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45t0s5f4.aspx) operator for exactly the purpose you seem to want. For simple types it's analogous to `sizeof`, but it behaves somewhat differently for complex types like structs etc...

Comment: AFAICT even `__declspec(align(4u))` is not allowed. And that's fairly constant too.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than asking:
**Why is the sizeof expression not a compile-time constant like 2, 4, 8, etc.?**

(because, actually, it **is** a compile time constant just like those examples. (: barring Variable Length Arrays from the newer C standards, for which it must be a run time expression :))

It would be better to ask:
**Why is it that `align(...)` does not accept a compile time constant like a sizeof expression?**

Microsoft defined **`__declspec(align(#))`** to only accept a small set of values:
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx

> "# is the alignment value. Valid entries are integer powers of two from 1 to 8192 (bytes), such as 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64."

So even with simple constants, not just any value is allowed.  **`__declspec(align(7))`** would not be allowed, as it isn't a power of 2.  Even simple expressions like **`__declspec(align(4+4))`** are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In the C Standard

> The **sizeof** operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such
>   a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member. The
>   _Alignof operator shall not be applied to a function type or an incomplete type.
>
> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
>   the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
>   is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
>   is an integer constant.

Comment: How is that helpful here? We are not even talking about C but C++ and the issue comes from some MSVC extension and not the standard.